# jQuery: Prevent child from inheriting the parent's attributes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

With jQuery: How do I prevent the children (`<span>`) from inheriting the parents' (`<p>`) attributes? I've been working on and researching this for 2+ hours; nothing has worked.

Problem section:

`$("p").not("span").css("cursor", "pointer");`

`<p>...<span>...</span></p>`

Full code:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<style>body {font-family:Arial,san-serif;font-size:25pt;}</style>
<body>
<p>Always shown | <span>Show/Hide</span></p>
<p>Always shown | <span>Show/Hide</span></p>
</body>

<script>
//Change pointer to a hand:
$("p").not("span").css("cursor", "pointer");
//Show & Hide by clicking on "Always shown":
function handler(event) {
  var target = $(event.target);
  if (target.is("p")) {
    target.children().toggle();
  }
}
$("body").click(handler).find("span").hide();
</script>
```

Comment: can you give an example about how you want it work?

Comment: this is a pure CSS issue... best solution is overriding what you don't want the child to inherit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you use css?

```
p{ cursor: pointer; }
p span{ cursor: default; }
```

Comment: if span is the p children, the correct sintax is p > span

Comment: @MTS Your selector will only target direct child elements which is fine but also not required or better in this case - p span is a perfectly correct way to target that span

Comment: Children are not nested, are direct.

Comment: It's up to the OP to determine the specificity of the selectors. I'm just giving  him a generic solution to his question.

Answer (score 2):

The expression `$("p").not("span")` literally means *"select `p` elements that are not `spans`"*. Obviously it is always true.

You want to check if `p` does not contain `span` children:

```
$("p:not(:has(span))").css("cursor", "pointer");
```

However, for this task you should probably go with CSS solution, rather then javascript.

Answer (score 1):

You could try this: [fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/qta4dgew/1/)

```
p:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
}
span:hover {
    cursor: default;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this approach also if you want to be done on Jquery :

```
$("p").css("cursor", "pointer");
$("p span").css("cursor", "default");
```